# Django model add property to fields in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

```
class Country(models.Model):
    status        = models.BooleanField()
    country_name  = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    country_flag  = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

class Offers(models.Model):      
    @property
    def flag_from(self):
        return self.country.country_flag
    
    status  = models.BooleanField()
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country',  db_index=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    .....other_normal_fields
```

So when i'm trying to get one row, and print my custom field Doesn't shows only when print it directly:

```
line=Offers.objects.get(pk=1)
print(line)
### here shows only normal fields
print(line.flag_form)
### now ok
```

also when i convert line to dict custom field dissappear, but i need it there

How it can be fixed?

Comment: What is `self.country.country_flag` share your full model.

Comment: Do you mean you want `flag_from` value by `print(line)`?

Comment: Added Country's model

Comment: Reply to my previous comment.

Comment: I need "flag_from" in the line like other fields

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by that? Can you explain?

Comment: Then you have to call it wherever you need it as it is a method not a value

Comment: Sunderam Dubey, he means when he converts the model object to a dictionary the method isn't added as one of the keys to it

Comment: i need to convert "line" to dict and pass it dicted to other functions and do not rewrite code everywhere i need that fields

Comment: "when i convert line to dict custom field dissappear, but i need it there" 
What is the method you use to convert the instance to a dict ?

Answer (score 1):

Given a comment of yours perhaps this answers your question.

```py
def getOfferDictionary(pk):
    line = Offers.objects.get(pk=pk)
    lineDict = {
        'status': line.status,
        'country': line.country.country_name,
        'flag_from': line.flag_from,
        # other properties you need
    }
    return lineDict
```

Keep in mind however this really isn't a good way of doing this, I recommend formatting the data locally to suit the views need instead of creating such a small reformatting, for which personally I cannot see a use

Comment: Ok, so what's the solution?

Comment: The solution depends on what you are trying to do, I cannot give you a ready solution since you didn't post enough of the views method

Comment: i need to get dict where are all fields with my custom
also i don't want to update whole project, so i need a beautifull solution
like that:
line = Offers.objects.get(pk=1)
print(line)
{'id':1,'status':True,'country_flag':""}

Comment: And now you can use the function getOfferDictionary(1) to get such a dictionary, you just need to add the rest of the fiels that you need to it. I don't undestand the issue

Comment: In that case i'll have to make changes everywhere in project where i'm making query to that model, so it's not a good way for me

Comment: No, make changes just in the function. Then use the function wherever you need

Comment: And i have to add function everywhere in project. It's not a good way

Comment: You have code, the code doesn't provide the required results. I really don't see how you could fix this situation without rewriting some code.

Comment: Yes, i understand your solution, but i hope there is a way without rewrite whole project )

Answer (score 1):

`flag_from` is a property of the `Offers` model, and not a field stored in the database. So, when you call `print(line)`, Django is simply displaying the fields that are stored in the database for the `Offers` model.

You can add it to the dictionary using the property name as the key so:

```py
line = Offers.objects.get(pk=1)
some_dict = {
    'status': line.status,
    'country': line.country.country_name,
    'flag_from': line.flag_from,
}
print(some_dict)
```

> **Note:** Django by default add `s` as the suffix to the model so it is better to name it is as `Offer` instead of `Offers`.

Comment: Thanks but it's not a solution

Comment: @Yuretz why what do you exactly want?

Comment: @Yuretz you should see how to make [repro].

Comment: see other comments please